# Pandas - true/false if TODAY is smallest value in past N days

Tags: python, pandas

How would I create another column (called CONDITION) in a dataframe that displays TRUE/FALSE if TODAY (current row/value) is the smallest in the last N days?

For example, the value in the PRICE column today (shown as 10/09/2019 below) is 10.  All of the values in the last eight days before 10/09/2019 are less than 10, so I want the value for today (10/09/2019) in the CONDITION column to be TRUE.

```
DATE          PRICE        CONDITION
10/01/2019    43           FALSE
10/02/2019    44           FALSE
10/03/2019    45           FALSE
10/04/2019    40           FALSE
10/05/2019    13           FALSE
10/06/2019    15           FALSE
10/07/2019    22           FALSE
10/08/2019    20           FALSE
10/09/2019    10           TRUE
10/10/2019    15           FALSE
```

This would apply to every row in the dataframe.  I want to do this without iterows, looking for a vectorized way or a rolling window or something.

Comment: Can you add a sample dataframe and expected output to this question?

Comment: I just added the basic example I describe in the post

Comment: maybe you need [rolling window](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=dataframe+rolling)

Answer (score 0):

Using rolling window with `min(x) == x[-1]` I can get it. To use `[-1]` I needed `raw=True`

Problem makes first `8` rows for window with size `9`.

Using

```
df['CONDITION'] = df['PRICE'].rolling(9).apply(lambda x:min(x) == x[-1], raw=True)
```

I get

```
         DATE  PRICE  CONDITION
0  10/01/2019     43        NaN
1  10/02/2019     44        NaN
2  10/03/2019     45        NaN
3  10/04/2019     40        NaN
4  10/05/2019     13        NaN
5  10/06/2019     15        NaN
6  10/07/2019     22        NaN
7  10/08/2019     20        NaN
8  10/09/2019     10        1.0
9  10/10/2019     15        0.0
```

Next I have to convert `NaN` to `0` and then I can convert all to `bool` using `.fillna(0).astype(bool)`

```
df['CONDITION'] = df['PRICE'].rolling(9).apply(lambda x:min(x) == x[-1], raw=True).fillna(0).astype(bool)
```

Result

```
         DATE  PRICE  CONDITION
0  10/01/2019     43      False
1  10/02/2019     44      False
2  10/03/2019     45      False
3  10/04/2019     40      False
4  10/05/2019     13      False
5  10/06/2019     15      False
6  10/07/2019     22      False
7  10/08/2019     20      False
8  10/09/2019     10       True
9  10/10/2019     15      False
```

---

Full working example

```
text = '''DATE          PRICE
10/01/2019    43
10/02/2019    44
10/03/2019    45
10/04/2019    40
10/05/2019    13
10/06/2019    15
10/07/2019    22
10/08/2019    20
10/09/2019    10
10/10/2019    15'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')

df['CONDITION'] = df['PRICE'].rolling(9).apply(lambda x:min(x) == x[-1], raw=True).fillna(0).astype(bool)

print(df)
```